# Copying attribute between different models' object but with the same attributes name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

** The original question here does not correctly explain what my problem is, Sorry to readers. Could you please refer to the "updated" part? Thanks **

Say I have two models - `Questions` and `SolvedQuestions`. What I want to do is to copy the solved `Questions` to `SolvedQuestions`. The model would look like this: `Questions(id: integer, content: string, user_id: integer)` and `SolvedQuestions(id: integer, question_id: integer, content: string, user_id: integer, solver_id: integer, solved_at: datetime )`

So the question being is there any way to copy the attributes from Questions to SolvedQuestions which have the same attribute name, except explicitly copy the value one by one? The reason being that: 1. That could be more robust in the future when new fields being added to Questions and SolvedQuestions.; 2. Time-saving.

Any thoughts? Thank you :)

Updated:
I do agree that a status attribute would do! I think I have picked a very bad example so please accept my apologies. The question I am trying to solve is that users can edit the `Questions` so I need to keep an instance of all historic questions.

In this case, I should use the example: `Questions` and `QuestionsHistories`. That's why I want to copy an image of Questions to QuestionHistories... Thank you!

Comment: Won't it lead to duplicacy of the data like content?

Comment: Oh, let me explain a bit more. What I want to do is when the Question is solved, it will be removed from the `Questions` model. This is to keep the `Questions` model slim: containing only unsolved current questions.

Comment: So why not just adding a `status` field in the `Question` model. And add a conditional association to `Solution` model if the question status is `solved`. And keep the default value of the `status` to be `unsolved`. I think this structure is more meaningful.

Comment: Sorry, I think I have taken a very bad example. What I really want to do is to keep a history of any changes in `Question`. So, that should be `Questions` with `QuestionsHistory`... Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better structure

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base      
end

class SolvedQuestion < Question
  # when solved, set solved as true and
  # set question_id in solver.
  has_many :solvers
end

class Solver < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :solved_question
end

#Migration
create_table questions do |t|
  t.solved :boolean, default: false
  # others
end
```

Just plain basic ActiveRecord settings. No fancy stuff needed.

Comment: I love this idea. One question: If `SolvedQuestion` is the child of `Question`, will SolvedQuestion be counted if I am counting/calling `Question`? Thanks!

Comment: @Quin, that's sure thing. Any question, solved or unsolved, is a question. However you can query unsolved question by checking if `solved` is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think so the best way is to use only one model Question and add a boolean field like solved?  and also move solver_id and solved_at in Questions model.

You can filter out with the help of scope

```
scope :solved, where(:solved => true)
scope :not_solved, where(:solved => false)
```

Comment: Agree! I think my example is bad. What I need is to keep a history of Questions so each time when a question is edited, the old one will be saved. Thanks for the response!! :)

Comment: But in your case nothing change so it will only duplicate your data.